# Submit form using <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit

I am trying to submit a form through onclick event on  tag. I have tried triggering document.myform.submit(), this.form.submit(), parentNode.submit() etc. but none of this is working! Using a submit button, the code works fine. But I want to use  tag in place of that. Need some help.

```
            <form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST" action="process_edit_questionnaire.php?project=<?php echo $project_id; ?>">
                <input name="module" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $module_id;?>"/>
                <input name="project" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $project_id;?>"/>
                <input name="hidden_ques_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data_array_ques[$j]['ques_id'];?>"/>

            <div id="question_block">

                <div id="serial_block">
                    <p id="s_original_<?php echo $j+1; ?>"><a href="#" onclick="showSelectBox(<?php echo $j+1; ?>)">Serial : 
                        <?php 
                        if($data_array_ques[$j]['ques_position']==NULL){ 
                            echo $j+1;                            
                        } 
                        else { 
                            echo $data_array_ques[$j]['ques_position'];         
                        } ?></a></p>
                    <p id="s_select_box_<?php echo $j+1; ?>" style="display: none;">Serial : 
                        <select name="serial">
                          <?php for($p=1;$p<=count($data_array_ques);$p++){ ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $p; ?>" <?php if($p==$data_array_ques[$j]['ques_position']){ echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?> ><?php echo $p; ?></option>
                          <?php }  ?>
                        </select>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div id="question_text">
                    <a href="#" onclick="showTextBox(<?php echo $j+1; ?>)"><p id="q_original_<?php echo $j+1; ?>"><?php echo $data_array_ques[$j]['ques_text']; ?></p></a>
                    <p id="q_text_box_<?php echo $j+1; ?>" style="display:none;"><textarea id="ques_text" name="ques_text" rows="3" cols="30"><?php echo $data_array_ques[$j]['ques_text']; ?></textarea></p>                     
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="menu_block">
                <a href="" onclick="document.myform.submit()">Save Changes</a> |
                <a href="delete_question.php?project=<?php echo $project_id; ?>&module=<?php echo $module_id; ?>">Delete This Question</a>
            </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: if it works and helped you might be nice to accept an answer here thats how this site works :)

Comment: Hold on a minute... I'm seeing PHP output `$j` a lot and it looks like an iterator... is this entire thing occurring in a loop? Are you outputting multiple copies of this form? If so that would mean there are multiple forms with the same ID and name, you'd need to add `$j` to ID and name like you do with everything else. If not, please disregard.

Answer (score 78):

you can do it like this with raw javascript

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="my_form" method="post" action="mailto://test@test.com">
            <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit();">submit</a>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

For those asking why I have a `href` element in my anchor tag, its because it's a compulsory part of an anchor tag, it may well work without but it's not to spec. So if you want to guarantee rendering etc you must give the engine a fully formed tag. So the above achieves this. You will see `href="#"` used sometimes but this is not always wanted as the browser will change the page position.

Comment: it prevents the default behavior of click event of `<a>` tag.

Comment: last two solutions didn't work. I dont know how to use jQuery.

Comment: @ Krystan, I know this works, but dont know why its not working in my code. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: In what way is this not working? Do you get a javascript error? Does the page do anything? Can you provide a link where it fails and with which browser & version?

Comment: Don't forget the id="my_form" on your <form> tag.

Comment: I'm curious about the reason that href="javascript:{}", is there a reason? I used  href="#" and it works fine.

Answer (score 15):

If jquery is allowed then you can use following code to implement it in the easiest way as :

```
<a href="javascript:$('#form_id').submit();">Login</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:$('form').submit()">Login</a>
```

You can use following line in your head tag () to import jquery into your code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This of course works without jQuery too: _<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('my_form').submit();">Login</a>_

Answer (score 6):

Submit your form like this ...

Your HTML code

```
    <form name="myform" action="handle-data.php"> Search: <input type='text' name='query' />
     <a href="javascript: submitform()">Search</a> 
   </form>
```

JavaScript Code

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function submitform() {   document.myform.submit(); } 
   </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already tried that. No results. I guess I have some problems in the code. But don't know what..

Comment: @Potheek - if there is nay prob try to pu alert , make use of debugger that will give you an idea, because this is the final code that you can make use of it for submiting form on link

Comment: why have you downvoted me when there is no jquery as i removed it in my edit way before your downvote, you would do best to read comments before you downvote

Comment: @Rana, the javascript function got called but the form did not get submitted :(

Comment: isnt better to write this code ==> `<a onclick="this.parentElement.submit()">search</a>`

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

Suppose HTML like this :

```
   <form id="myform" name="myform" method="POST" action="process_edit_questionnaire.php?project=<?php echo $project_id; ?>">
      <div id="question_block">
            testing form
        </div>
     <a href="javascript: submit();">Submit</a>
        </form>
```

#### JS :

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
     function submit()
      {
         document.forms["myform"].submit();
      }
   </script>
```

you can check it out here : http://jsfiddle.net/Zm426/7/

Comment: I have tried exactly what you have written here but that didn't work:(

Comment: what kind of error in Console? have u put function in `Script` tag

Comment: @ Jigs, I know it works, I think there is something wrong in my code. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

```
<form  id="myform_id" action="/myMethode"  role="form"  method="post" > 
   <a  href="javascript:$('#myform_id').submit();" >submit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: When you post HTML, XML, or anything tag based, it's very important that you format your code properly. Otherwise it gets formatted as a part of the post. See [the help center](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 3):

Clean and simple:

```
  <form action="/myaction" method="post" target="_blank">
    <!-- other elements -->
    <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit();">Submit</a>
 </form>
```

In case of opening form `action` url in a new tab (`target="_blank"`):

```
  <form action="/myaction" method="post" target="_blank">
    <!-- other elements -->
    <a href="#" onclick="this.parentNode.submit();">Submit</a>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason for not using a **submit button** and then styling it with css to match your other **a** tags?

I think this would reduce your dependency on having javascript enabled and still get the desired result.

Comment: The question specifically asks how to do it with an `<a>` element. The OP stated that it worked well with a submit button. While it might be a valid objection in some cases, disabled JavaScript isn’t a big issue nowadays (and also not part of the question).

Comment: Apologies, you're absolutely right the question does state that.  However I can't understand why you have taken the time to promote solutions that while work, require more code and will work in fewer situations.  The issue of javascript really depends on how much you value potential customers, no matter what pap they are browsing with.

If I'm missing something about what I should contribute to, let me know and I'll delete it off

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    $('#deleteFrm').submit();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" id="deleteFrm" method="POST">
  <a id="btnSubmit">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use "return false" instead of useing some javascript in the href-tag:

```
<form id="">
...
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit(); return false;">send form</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden submit button and click it using java script/jquery like this:

```
  <form id="contactForm" method="post" class="contact-form">

        <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" style="display:none;" data-validate="contact-form">Hidden Button</button>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="myClass" onclick="$('#submitBtn').click();">Submit</a>

  </form>
```