# onclick event fails on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I click on the icon in the search box it submits the search. Works perfectly on Chrome... only tested firefox as other browser but fails (wont do anything) have I done something wrong?

```
<form class="custom-search-form navbar-search" action="/search" method="GET" >
    <input name="keyword" class="autocomplete span4" placeholder="Search for an Attraction...">
    <a href="javascript:(.submit());" onclick="submit()" class="icon-search"></a>
</form>
```

The issue is with the a href.

Comment: what in the world is :`href="javascript:(.submit());"`? Looks like an error to me.

Comment: @epascarello It is a way to call Javascript.

Comment: I guess it is the same as `this.submit()`, right?

Comment: I am sorry but I never seen or used like this href="javascript:(.submit());"

Comment: @gskartwii: Really, are you sure about that? I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . ` in chrome. In IE I get "SCRIPT1002: Syntax error" http://jsfiddle.net/4HYZY/show/

Comment: @epascarello Oh, true. Not my fault.

Comment: what does firebug say? Try it: http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 1):

what is it `javascript:(.submit());` in `href`

```
 <a href="javascript:(.submit());" onclick="submit()" class="icon-search"></a>
```

it should be

```
<a href="#" onclick="submit(); return false;" class="icon-search"></a>
```

Comment: Not adding "return false" on the onclick event can produce unexpected result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer.
[Submit form using <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039968/submit-form-using-a-tag)

Firefox is complaining that 'submit' is not defined.

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mspaly/eje6H/1/

```
<form id="my_form" class="custom-search-form navbar-search" action="/search" method="GET" >
                    <input name="keyword" class="autocomplete span4" placeholder="Search for an Attraction...">
                    <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('my_form').submit()" class="icon-search">search</a>
                </form>
```

Note also that you would have to add an ID to your form element

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this for the href:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit(); return false;" class="icon-search"></a>
```

And somthing like this for the form:

```
<form id="myForm" class="custom-search-form navbar-search" action="/search" method="GET" >
```

Does it solve the problem ?

Comment: Can you provide me with a Fiddle of your issue ? Or the url of your page ? The problem must be somewhere else, the code I gave you is valid.

Answer (score 0):

or, better bur not perfect :

```
<a href="javascript:submit();" class="icon-search"></a>
```

best would be to use an event listener

Answer (score 0):

If you want an element to behave like a button, you should use `<button>` and not `<a>`.

`<button onclick="submit()">submit()</button>`

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<a href="#" onclick=".submit(); submit(); return false;" class="icon-search"></a>
```

Comment: @Scalpweb He is calling it in the href.

Comment: Still looks like an error to me. The javascript console is probably returning an error.