# Form submit through a specific button

Tags: php

Here is my form:

```
 <form method= "post" action= "edit.php">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 " id= "show"> <img alt="User Pic" src="http://babyinfoforyou.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/avatar-300x300.png" class="img-circle img-responsive">
        <a data-original-title="Upload Image" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
         </div>
        <div class=" col-md-9 col-lg-9 "> 
          <table class="table table-user-information">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><span id= "keep"><?php echo $firstname;  ?></span><input id= "change" value= "<?php echo $firstname;  ?>" style= "display:none;" name="name"></td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth</td>
                <td><span id= "keep1"><?php echo $birthday; ?></span><input id= "change1" value= "<?php echo $birthday; ?>" style= "display:none;" name="bday"></td>
              </tr>

                 <tr>
                     <tr>
                <td>Gender</td>
                <td><span id= "keep2"><?php echo $gender; ?></span><input id= "change2" value= "<?php echo $gender; ?>" style= "display:none;" name="gen"></td>
              </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Country</td>
                <td><span id= "keep3">US</span><input id= "change3" value= "US" style= "display:none;" name="country"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><span id= "keep4"><a href="mailto:info@support.com"><?php echo $email; ?></a></span><input id= "change4" value= "<?php echo $email; ?>" style= "display:none;" name="mail"></td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
         <div class="panel-footer">
                <a data-original-title="Broadcast Message" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></a>
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <a href="#" data-original-title="Edit this user" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" onclick = 'showMe()'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                    <a data-original-title="Save this user" data-toggle="tooltip" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></i></a>

                </span>
            </div>
    </form>
```

How can I make only the "save" button go to edit.php not the others? Now when I click on it doesn't go anywhere, Then on edit. php I want it to update and return to this page with the updated version, I'm just stuck on how to get it to go to edit.php

Comment: for the first question, you would need javascript for this, not php. 2nd, I'm not going to help you with, as you need to put some effort into it too.

Comment: when there's no php to accompany the question, it makes it "unclear" and "too broad" all at the same time.

Comment: Then what could I do? is there no other simple way? @Hallur

Comment: I don't need php right now, I just want the save button to be the one to go to edit.php

Comment: ...you need ajax for that then.

Answer (score 1):

you need add the submit botton.

```
<button type="submit"  class="btn >SAVE</button>
```

Comment: I have it as:                             <a data-original-title="Save this user" data-toggle="tooltip" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></i></a>

Comment: you need add a button element(<button></button>) . you have a link (<a></a>)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding form submission:

- An HTML button will submit its parent `form` if it  is `type="submit"` or has no `type` attribute (it defaults to `submit`).
- An HTML button will not submit its parent `form` if it is
  `type="button"`.
- Since you seem insistent on using an `<a>` tag rather than an `<input>` or `<button>` tag to submit your form, see: [Submit form using <a> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039968/submit-form-using-a-tag). But this solution is *not* recommended and is fairly bad practice if there's no reason to not use an `<input>` or `<button>` tag, since JavaScript does not work across all browsers, is disabled by default in others, and can always be disabled by users, in all cases rendering your form useless.

Regarding the rest of your question:

- Without accompanying PHP it's difficult to know anything about your situation.

Comment: I have it as type= "submit" but its nor working, did I insert it in the wrong area?

Comment: You have an `<a>` tag that is `type="submit"`. You need an `<input>` or `<button>` element that is `type="submit"`. If you want to submit using an `<a>` tag you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: If I just <button> the way my button looks like changes

Comment: So? Update your CSS. 'Out-of-the-box' form submission only works with `<input>` or `<button>` elements. If you insist on using an `<a>` tag you'll need to use JavaScript to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Please add submit button to your form.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit-btn" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Comment: I want it too look like this                            <a data-original-title="Save this user" data-toggle="tooltip" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved"></i></a>
How should I make this one go to edit.php

Answer (score 0):

Give an `id` for your `form`

```
<form id="myform" method= "post" action= "edit.php">
```

Now add this javascript to your anchor tag

```
onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();"
```

Now your anchor tag will look like

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit();" 
   data-original-title="Save this user" data-toggle="tooltip" 
   class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved">
  </i></a>
```